# Is there a way to write this code in a short way?

Tags: java, arrays, jframe

I've been making a program where i made a `comboBox` then add an `actionlistener` to it that if I clicked it a frame would appear.

Code:

```
String menulist [] = {"", "Array", "BubbleSort" ," - Selection Sort"," - Insertion Sort"," - Merge Sort","Recursion"," - Factorial"," - Anagramming"," - Towers of Hanoi","Stacks","Trees"," - Types of Trees","Binary Tree","Shell Sort","Quick Sort","Hash Table","Graphs"};
    final JComboBox SelectMenu = new JComboBox(menulist);
    SelectMenu.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17)); 

    SelectMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int list = SelectMenu.getSelectedIndex();



            if(list == 1){

                //Array
                JFrame frameArray = new JFrame();
                frameArray.setBounds(100, 100, 830, 601);
                frameArray.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frameArray.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
                frameArray.setVisible(true);

                JLabel lblArray = new JLabel("Array");
                lblArray.setFont(new Font("Lucida Bright", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 25));
                lblArray.setBounds(368, 63, 122, 41);
                frameArray.getContentPane().add(lblArray);

                JLabel AnArrayIs = new JLabel();
                AnArrayIs.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                AnArrayIs.setText("An array is a systematic arrangement of similar objects, usually in rows and columns.");
                AnArrayIs.setBounds(46, 103, 357, 432);
                frameArray.getContentPane().add(AnArrayIs);
```

I would be using if-else in that case I would be using a lot of if almost 16 of the example. Is there a way that I could write a shorter code for the frame? So i would just keep doing the if-else until the 16 index?

Thank you in advance!! (:

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1):

if the only thing you're changing is the label and the text then make a method like so:

```
      public Jframe getJframe(String label, String text){    
            JFrame frameArray = new JFrame();
            frameArray.setBounds(100, 100, 830, 601);
            frameArray.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frameArray.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            frameArray.setVisible(true);

            JLabel lblArray = new JLabel(label);
            lblArray.setFont(new Font("Lucida Bright", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 25));
            lblArray.setBounds(368, 63, 122, 41);
            frameArray.getContentPane().add(lblArray);

            JLabel AnArrayIs = new JLabel();
            AnArrayIs.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            AnArrayIs.setText(text);
            AnArrayIs.setBounds(46, 103, 357, 432);
            frameArray.getContentPane().add(AnArrayIs); 
            return frameArray;
            }
```

then your if statements or switch statement only have to look like:

```
Jframe myJframe = null;
if(list==1){
  myJframe = getJframe(menuList[1],"An array is.....")
} else if(list ==2){
  myJframe = getJframe(menuList[2],"BubbleSort is ...")
}....
```

I'd probably create constants for the definitions so you can change them easily, like:

```
public static final String ARRAY_DEFINITION = "An array is a ....";
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the code less complex is to create different `JFrame` subclasses to handle each of the indices.

The first index is "Array" so create a new `JFrame` subclass:

```
public class ArrayFrame extends JFrame {
    public ArrayFrame () {
        setBounds(100, 100, 830, 601);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Array");
        lbl.setFont(new Font("Lucida Bright", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 25));
        lbl.setBounds(368, 63, 122, 41);
        getContentPane().add(lbl);

        JLabel detailLbl = new JLabel();
        detailLbl.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        detailLbl.setText("An array is...");
        detailLbl.setBounds(46, 103, 357, 432);
        getContentPane().add(detailLbl); 
    }
}
```

In your if statement, create an instance of `ArrayFrame` and open the frame:

```
if (list == 1) {
    ArrayFrame frame = new ArrayFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

That's more maintainable and hides a lot of details which means it's more abstract. Everyone loves abstraction in OOP!

"Well, I still have to create 16 classes," you say. You can actually just create one class!

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame (String title, String details) {
        setBounds(100, 100, 830, 601);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(title);
        lbl.setFont(new Font("Lucida Bright", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 25));
        lbl.setBounds(368, 63, 122, 41);
        getContentPane().add(lbl);

        JLabel detailLbl = new JLabel();
        detailLbl.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        detailLbl.setText(details);
        detailLbl.setBounds(46, 103, 357, 432);
        getContentPane().add(detailLbl); 
    }
}
```

And you can just create this frame by calling the constructor like this:

```
if (list == 1) {
    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame ("Array", "An array is...");
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, consider using a switch instead of if statements.

Answer (score 0):

> I would be using if-else in that case I would be using a lot of if almost 16 of the example. Is there a way that I could write a shorter code for the frame? So i would just keep doing the if-else until the 16 index?

I think your best option is to use a `switch` statement instead of 16 if/else statements. It will be much simpler.

See this example in the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```